# Proper craftsmanship to mount Wi-Fi AP and ethernet cable to ceiling?

Tags: wiring, ceiling, low-voltage, ethernet

I'd like to add a ceiling-mounted Wi-Fi Access Point to the upper floor of an already existing house (USA, wood studs, built 1998).

I have access to the attic above and would run Category 6 ethernet (UTP, CMR or CMP) to this location.

If I use an AP like the Unifi AP Lite, which can be ceiling mounted, what's the best way to handle the "appearance" of the ethernet cable in the ceiling?   I believe the choices are:

- (a) **hole in ceiling**,  push the cable through the hole from above, and terminate the cable with a plastic 'RJ45' plug, or a fancy Category 6 version.  Cover the hole with the AP.  Mount  the AP with screws and drywall anchors to the drywall ceiling.  (The
  UBNT community [doesn't seem to worry about](https://community.ubnt.com/t5/UniFi-Wireless/Using-Wall-Mount-Instructions-to-Ceiling-Mount-a-UniFi-AP/m-p/923394/highlight/true#M68743) the weight of the
  AP.)
- (b) **wall plate on the ceiling** with keystone-style punchdown jack
  and a very short 6" patch cable to the AP (I believe it has a recess
  to stow the cable)
- (c) **old-work box** mounted to a ceiling stud (attic joist).  Bore a hole
  in the ceiling the size of the old-work box. Terminate the ethernet
  cable inside the old-work box.  (This seems like overkill).

Is a plain-old hole ("a") an okay way to go here--  Any concerns about losing the cable up into the hole?

And, I know they say "it's just as easy to pull two cables as one" but do I **really** need to pull two cables to this location? I can't imagine needing a second ethernet cable in the ceiling at this exact location!

Comment: IMHO "proper craftsmanship" would be your option (c). It's the way I like to think I'd do it ;) but I've never seen it done that way ...

Comment: Old work 4” round.  I can’t remember if the holes in the bracket were correct or if we had to drill our own, but the device fits rather well on 4” round.

Comment: For this low voltage I would not use a old work box (not required for cable/WiFi) I would use a low voltage ring cut the hole get a cover plate with the appropriate size hole then put the rj45 plug on quick cheap the hole is sealed somewhat so heating and cooling are not affected. If you want to move it later you can slip the plate into the attic and put a solid cover plate.

Comment: I would not pull an extra cable to the location in a house. Done right, the AP has no visible cable when installed, so what you do above it (as LV cable) does not matter. If you have dreams of absurd $700 APs, they do make versions that will take two cables and use them both, but in a house - unlikely.

Comment: @EdBeal we used old work specifically because it’s attic above with blown in insulation.  Low voltage rings don’t contain that as well.  The AP looks rather nice with no exposed cable, I have the same one as the OP is proposing.

Comment: @tyson a low voltage "ring" 100% is as good as an old work box at much less it all depends on the cover plate,  to get technical and in my experiance with the low voltage "ring or opening" they are more secure as the screws go through the sheet metal on both sides of the sheetrock not just 2 tiny arms at corners of a plastic box unless you want to spend 5x? As much on a quality metal old work that has wings to support the box then add a bushing so the cable is protected and the seal in both the ring is the same as an old work box it depends on the cover.

Comment: @EdBeal I agree that in an uninsulated *wall* a LV ring is fabulous!  Ceiling with loose fill insulation above, old work keeps the insulation from falling out every time you need to take the device loose.  Also wall they do exist, it’s harder to find 4” round LV trim rings, there are many thousands of choices in 1 and 2 gang rectangular.

Comment: @Tyson I assume you meant “while” (via dictation)!   Thanks all for the good discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very short answer but I'd just use the mounting disc that comes with the AP, drill a small hole in the ceiling and put a plug on the cable and you're done.  The instructions for the AP show how to mount it but it's really just a matter of three screws and drywall anchors and when mounted no cable visible.  Look at the disc and you'll see where the hole needs to be.

Comment: If you have access above and want to overkill it, you can use the metal plate and machine-thread screws and nuts intended for acoustic tile mounting. As for the cable itself, just poke a hole in the right spot and terminate - it's low voltage cable, the AP mount and AP are a perfectly good LV "box" and nothing more is needed, though you can overkill that to your heart's content. DO be careful about the angle of the cable, though, as sharp bends are bad. Some of the newer heavy metal UniFi HD APs might rate an anchor (or again the plate, which is even better, as you do have access above.)